# Date column changes when I upload a shapefile with this column type to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a FeatureCollection in my Assets in Google Earth Engine, which is the result of uploading some shapefile containing some productive areas from the company I work for.

When I import this collection to my script and print it, I can see the columns which contain date values in the previous shapefile are now changed to type `Long` in the FeatureCollection.

How can I import this FeatureCollection without having this problem?

Comment: How are the date values formatted before you upload? Like YYYY-MM-dd or something else?

Comment: Hi @JonasV , the date are in this format: dd/MM/YYYY (separated by "/"). Do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: What I am thinking now, is that Earth Engine automatically converts columns of type date to their own representation of dates, which is in miliseconds since 1970-01-01. Have a look at this answer to see how dates can be handled and converted in EE: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358089/change-date-format-into-readable-format-in-gee/358094#358094

Comment: If you want to keep it as a string for some reason, you can probably change the data type in the shapefile to a character string. Then I don't think Earth Engine will do anything with it.

Comment: About the representation os date type, I've already read the documentation, but thanks for sending me the link anyway =]. About what you recommended, I'll try this solution as soon as possible and I'll give you a feedback! Thanks again!